# How can I count number of " !=null " fields on a record?

Tags: apex, trigger, loop, basics

My question is about challenge when Opportunity is created specific fields must be populated. How can I count the fields which are not null from specific fields?

```
 integer counter;
 integer oppValue;
    for (Opportunity : Trigger.new) {
        if (myOpp.Amount != null) {
            oppValue= 1;}
        else if {oppValue= 0;}
     // Same loop repeates for several fields assigning value to oppValue. 

    counter = oppValue ++;
    System.debug(counter);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While I am aware that this issue is solved and the code mentioned above works, there is a simpler way of accomplishing this requirement and hence thought of sharing it here.

The above scenario can be easily accomplished declaratively through a Formula Field given the fact that you do not exceed the [formula field character limit of 3900 characters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_field_limits.htm&type=5).

Create a simple formula field of type Number as below and it will count all the non-blank fields.

```
IF(ISBLANK(TEXT(Field1__c)),0,1)  //Add this only for text fields
+ IF(ISBLANK(Field2__c),0,1)
+ IF(ISBLANK(Field3__c),0,1)
+ IF(ISBLANK(Field4__c),0,1)
.
.
+ IF(ISBLANK(FieldN__c),0,1)
```

This should be cleaner and will save you a ton of effort of writing test code.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*Put all the fields to check if those are blank, You can also create a custom label OR custom setting */
Set<String> fields = new Set<String>{'Amount','Stagename'};
Integer counter = 0;
Map<Id,Integer> oppCounterMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();

for (Opportunity myOpp: Trigger.new) {
    for(String fieldName : fields){
        // Check if the field is Blank
        if(myOpp.get(fieldName) != null)
        counter++;
    }
    /*Map of Opportunity and the number of fields which are blank on the 
      resepective sObject */
    oppCounterMap.put(myOpp.Id, counter);
    counter= 0;
}
```

Comment: Amit, appreciate your effort. Thanks a lot! it worked.